# How to extend pseudo background color beyond center container but not screen width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hi guys i need your help, i am trying this alternating image and text design:

[image]

And I'm coding this in bootstrap, here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"><img src="images/image.png" class="img1 img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-10"><h4 class="details blue right">Lorem Ipsum text here...</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10"><h4 class="details green left">Lorem Ipsum text here...</h4></div>
        <div class="col-2"><img src="images/image.png" class="img2 img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"><img src="images/image.png" class="img3 img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-10"><h4 class="details orange right">Lorem Ipsum text here...</h4></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.container{
    max-width:960px;
}

.details.left:before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
height:100%;
background:inherit;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:0;
overflow:hidden;
border-top-right-radius:4px;
border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}
```

My problem is the width of the text background is overflowing the screen width and it creates a horizontal scroll, how do i clip the background so i won't have the scroll? i only want the background to overlap the center container not the screen width.

Comment: Not clear what are you askin

Comment: The background width of the text is overlapping the screen width which creates the horizontal scroll, i only intended the background to overlap the center container, not the screen width. how do i clip it?

Comment: Try removing the background: inherit from  your css

Comment: if i do that the background is cut off exactly at the edge of the center container, i want it to overlap till it reach the edge of the screen width but not over it.

Comment: You have given width: 100% try changing it in such a way so that it reaches the edge of the centrer container.. use 5 values.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle we better give a solution for your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/paolor0ck5/e53f9gju/1/#&togetherjs=M8LByCCRaV

Comment: The fiddle doesn't look like your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is the width of the text background is overflowing the
>   screen width and it creates a horizontal scroll, how do i clip the
>   background so i won't have the scroll?

Wrap your container in an outer wrapper and give it `overflow: hidden` and give your html and body a zero margin

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I applied this to your [fiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/e53f9gju/3/), though it look far from you posted screen dump